# Gallery page at wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, gallery, media

I got a problem :/
I have a plugins for the users can send files for my media gallery, this is working perfeclty, but, I want to show my media library in a page or post of wordpress. This is possible ?
I guess i need a plugin or script right ? Thx :D

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you are talking about wordpress.com or wordpress.org but it should be the same.

Use the [gallery] shortcode in your page/post and it will output your images from your media library. You can specify images by using their id's, read more about it here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode

If you want to display other file formats, it is possible.